# How can I round down numbers of varying sizes to 3 significant digits in scientific notation in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to apply the ROUNDDOWN function for a cell that performs a calculation based on three cells with a number that can range from 10^6 to 10^-8. I aim for numbers that give something like 5.587e-4 turns into 5.58e-4 when displayed in a calculated cell.

The normal code for the calculated cell is as follows:

```
=IFERROR(IF(B2="N/A",N/A,IF(B2>20,N/A,E2/A2)),N/A)
```

The data for the calculated cell is as follows:

| 1 | A | B | C | D | E | Calculated Cell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1.00e-4 | 15 | 14 | 18 | 15.66667 | 156666.6667 |

In a separate cell, I attempted to implement the ROUNDDOWN function to see if it works. The code is

```
=IFERROR(ROUNDDOWN(IF(B2="N/A",N/A,IF(B2>20,N/A,E2/A2)),2),N/A)
```

The comparison table is as follows:

|  | Scientific Notation | Actual Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ROUNDDOWN Function | 1.57e+05 | 156666.66 |
| Normal Code | 1.57e+05 | 156666.6667 |

As you can see, the number is rounding down the to the hundredths place for the actual value and **then** changing it to scientific notation, which rounds to the closest number of 1.57e+05. I understand that the ROUNDDOWN function is working as intended, but I'm at a loss on how to round down numbers based on their scientific notation form rather than their actual value form. Is there a solution through other functions for this?

Comment: Would you provide some samples of the expected result? It is not clear to me what are you trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `ROUNDDOWN` to 3 sig digits:

```
=IFERROR(IF(B2="N/A",NA(),IF(B2>20,NA(),ROUNDDOWN(E2/A2,3-1-INT(LOG10(ABS(E2/A2)))))),NA())
```

The `3` in the formula represents the number of significant digits.

[image]